# Optimizing Palindrome substring identification

Tags: java, performance, substring, palindrome, processing-efficiency

I'm currently trying to find a way to get my program to run more efficiently. If anyone has any ideas on how to optimize my program, i would appreciate it a lot. 
Also, the output has to display in alphabetic order without any duplicates.

```
package Palindrome;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Palindrome {

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        Scanner scan;   
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scan.hasNext()) {

    subPal(scan.next());
            }
        if (scan != null) {
            scan.close();
        }}


private static void subPal(String str) {
    String s1 = "";
    int N = str.length();
    ArrayList<String> palindromeArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= N; j++) {
            int k = i + j - 1;
            if (k >= N)
                continue;
            s1 = str.substring(j, i + j);
            if (s1.equals(new StringBuilder(s1).reverse().toString())&& !palindromeArray.contains(s1)) {
                palindromeArray.add(s1);
            }
        }

    }
    Collections.sort(palindromeArray);
    for (String s : palindromeArray)
        System.out.println(s );

}

}
```

Comment: why do you think it needs optimization?

Comment: well, I'm trying to submit it through an online judging system (Kattis) in order to learn more about Java, and expand my knowledge of it.

Comment: And it's not supposed to run for more than 8 seconds, And it always exceeds the time limit

Comment: A more appropriate StackExchange site would be [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since your question is about improving working code. Note that I'm not saying you won't have a correct answer here.

Comment: Here's the post on CR: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/146142/outputs-all-substrings-that-are-palindromes-in-a-given-string-in-alphabetical-o

Comment: thanks for linking that for me! I'm sort of new to stack exchange